# Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions for Youtube data api v3 search

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Getting 400 error while exploring [**YoutubeData API V3**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it) for search. 
 It accepts parameters like:

part = snippet

location = 12.9667,77.5667

locationRadius = 50km

But it gives me the response below :

```
400 Bad Request


{
"error": {
 "errors": [
{
 "domain": "youtube.search",
 "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
 "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": ""
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem.
[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#errors) says

> Note that you must set the type parameter to video if you set a value for the eventType, videoCaption, videoCategoryId, videoDefinition, videoDimension, videoDuration, videoEmbeddable, videoLicense, videoSyndicated, or videoType parameters.

Though nothing mentioned about location parameter, adding `type = "video"` to parameter list has solved my problem.